# Transferring a 2D array from one class to another

Tags: java, class, multidimensional-array, transfer

I am attempting to take all the information that added by the user in the text fields, and then add them a 2D array. I have accomplish that by doing this:

```
int minorinput = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, panel1, "Choose Minor Stats", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);

        if(minorinput == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION)
        {
            int [][] pureMR = new int [4][4];

            pureMR[0][0] = Integer.parseInt(Melee.getText());
            pureMR[1][0] = Integer.parseInt(Ranged.getText());
            pureMR[2][0] = Integer.parseInt(RC.getText());
            pureMR[3][0] = Integer.parseInt(Negotiation.getText());

            pureMR[0][1] = Integer.parseInt(Dodge.getText());
            pureMR[1][1]= Integer.parseInt(Perception.getText());
            pureMR[2][1] = Integer.parseInt(Will.getText());
            pureMR[3][1] = Integer.parseInt(Procure.getText());

            pureMR[0][2] = Integer.parseInt(rideBox.getText());
            pureMR[1][2] = Integer.parseInt(rideBox2.getText());
            pureMR[2][2] = Integer.parseInt(artBox.getText());
            pureMR[3][2] = Integer.parseInt(art2.getText());

            pureMR[0][3] = Integer.parseInt(knowledgeBox.getText());
            pureMR[1][3] = Integer.parseInt(knowledge2Box.getText());
            pureMR[2][3] = Integer.parseInt(infoBox.getText());
            pureMR[3][3] = Integer.parseInt(info2Box.getText());
```

But I can't figure out how to transfer the array to a different class, where it will be used in an object constructor that will allow me to print via the objects toString method.

How should I be going about transferring the 2D array from class to class?

[Class I want to add the Array to:](http://pastebin.com/yFHTCJg0)

```
                    if(pureinput == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION)
                    {

                        String name = nameBox.getText();
                        String age = ageBox.getText();
                        String gender = genderBox.getText();
                        String bloodType = bloodBox.getText();
                        String height = heightBox.getText();
                        String weight = weightBox.getText();
                        String zodiac= zodiacBox.getText();
                        String work = workBox.getText();
                        String cover = coverBox.getText();
                        String breed = "Pure";
                        String sydrome = syndrome1Box.getText();

                        int[] pureBS = new int[4];
                        pureBS[0] = Integer.parseInt(bodyBox.getText());
                        pureBS[1] = Integer.parseInt(senseBox.getText());
                        pureBS[2] = Integer.parseInt(mindBox.getText());
                        pureBS[3] = Integer.parseInt(skillBox.getText());

                        int[] pureSS = new int[6];
                        pureSS[0] = Integer.parseInt(mHPBox.getText());
                        pureSS[1] = Integer.parseInt(stockBox.getText());
                        pureSS[2] = Integer.parseInt(savingsBox.getText());
                        pureSS[3] = Integer.parseInt(initBox.getText());
                        pureSS[4] = Integer.parseInt(moveBox.getText());
                        pureSS[5] = Integer.parseInt(dashBox.getText());

                        String origin = orginBox.getText();
                        String exp = ExperienceBox.getText();
                        String encounter = EncounterBox.getText();
                        String awake = AwakeningBox.getText();
                        int eRate = Integer.parseInt(EncroachmentRateBox.getText());
                        String impulse = ImpulseBox.getText();
                        int eRate2= Integer.parseInt(EncroachmentRateBox2.getText());


                        Character pure = new Character(name,age,bloodType,gender, height,weight,zodiac,work,cover,
                                                        breed,sydrome,pureBS, pureSS,origin,exp,encounter,awake,eRate,
                                                        impulse,eRate2, //Needs a 2D array here);

                        System.out.println(pure.pureToString());
```

[It creates this dialog box.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Dl0c.png)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way: simply call a setter method, and pass the array into the instance:

```
    if(minorinput == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
        int [][] pureMR = new int [4][4];

        // code to fill array

        // assuming your OtherClass has this type of setter method...
        // because if it doesn't, it NEEDS one.
        otherInstance.setPureMr(pureMR);
```

Where you get your reference to the otherInstance instance will depend totally on how your program is structured, information that we are not privy to at this moment.

Having said this, I do have to wonder if your 2D array is a kludge, if you're far better off creating a class to hold this information, and then passing an object of this class into your other instance.

Comment: What do you mean by otherInstance? Do I need create an object in the first class, the class I want the array to be transferred to, and that is otherInstance?

Comment: @Kas.C: you have stated that you want to transmit this information `"to another class"`, and "otherInstance" is that other class. How you create it, how you reference it will all depend on information that you have not told us, that we do not know. My guess is that you do not want to create a new instance, that you want to reference to an existing instance, but if you want a better answer, you will want to improve your question quite a bit, and tell us more of the pertinent missing details.

Comment: @Kas.C: understand that we only know what you show us and tell us, no more and no less.

Comment: Sorry, I'm having a hard time staying within the character limit. The class I want to add the array to is 1307 lines long. I've added more information. Thank you for your patience.